# Integrate Yammer API into iphone app?

Tags: iphone, oauth, yammer

Can anybody help me to integrate yammer into iphone app.

1. How to authenticate user?
2. How to get feed?
3. How to post messages?

Answer (score 1):

There is mobile SDK for iOS available from http://developer.yammer.com/mobile/. This will help you authenticate and perform those other tasks.